# How do I start Compositing in LXDE for programs like docky?

Tags: lxde, docky, compositing

Recently, I switched to LXDE due to performance issues with Unity. I've always liked LXDE, just I needed to tweak it to make it better. My favorit improvement is to add a dock bar to the bottom of the screen and move the panel to the top. However, Docky always asks for compositing. My various searches found ways to start it manually, but never a way for it to start with the UI. So my question is: How do I start compositing in LXDE to where it starts when I log in?

Answer (score 3):

When I clicked AskUbuntu to post this question, I searched one more thing and finally got the answer in the form of a youtube video. No tutorials exist that I could find. Therefore, please enjoy this post:

The first step is to install the manager that is going to be doing the work:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install xcompmgr`

This will go through the usual install routine. Once it is done, you need to run the following:

`leafpad ~/.config/autostart/xcompmgr.desktop`

And paste the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=XCompositing Manager
GenericName=Compiz
Comment=This enables Compositing for LXDE
Exec=xcompmgr -n
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=dropbox
Categories=
StartupNotify=false
Name[en_US]=Xcompmgr
Comment[en_US]=This was created by Geary
```

Save it and open your file manager to `~/.config/autostart` and run the xcompmgr plug in. If docky is running, you should see the bar blink and come back with the better graphics enabled.

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail please? Do you use the same switches when you start it? Is there a different way to set it to start?